# Trazer todos os registros de tabela com jpa e eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipse-link

Galera, estou com uma dúvida aqui no JPA.
Hoje eu tenho um método para buscar as UFs por ID, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public Uf consulta(Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = getEM();
    Uf uf = new Uf();
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        uf = em.find(Uf.class, id);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
        em.close(); //fecha o EntityManager        
    }
    return uf;
}
```

Tem alguma forma de buscar todos os registros do banco, sem precisar percorrer um por um ? Minha ideia é apresentar todos os registros em uma table, mas não sei se preciso consultar de um a um com o find dentro de um for e ir adicionando no Array por exemplo, ou se existe alguma maneira no jpa que traga tudo pra mim sem precisar de um for.
Qualquer dica será útil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o seu `em`, faça:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select u from Uf u");
List<Uf> ufs = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado!